WebSocketException: "SSL not available" in Python 2.7.5 on RHEL 9
I'm encountering an issue with my Python 2.7.5 application on RHEL 9 where I'm trying to establish a secure WebSocket connection. Despite having OpenSSL installed and verified, I keep getting a WebSocketException with the message "SSL not available." Here are the details:
Error Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 975, in handle_one_response
    self.run_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 922, in run_application
    self.result = self.application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/root/prism_vnc_proxy/prism_vnc_proxy/wsgi_http_handler.py", line 116, in handle
    return endpoint(environ, start_response_wrapper, **args)
  File "/root/prism_vnc_proxy/prism_vnc_proxy/wsgi_prism_websocket_proxy.py", line 161, in handle
    return self._handle(environ, start_response, server_url)
  File "/root/prism_vnc_proxy/prism_vnc_proxy/wsgi_prism_websocket_proxy.py", line 147, in _handle
    return do_proxy(environ, start_response)
  File "/root/prism_vnc_proxy/prism_vnc_proxy/wsgi_web_socket.py", line 145, in __call__
    self.handler(ws)
  File "/root/prism_vnc_proxy/prism_vnc_proxy/wsgi_prism_websocket_proxy.py", line 144, in do_proxy
    server = self._open_websock(environ, cookie, server_url)
  File "/root/prism_vnc_proxy/prism_vnc_proxy/wsgi_prism_websocket_proxy.py", line 84, in _open_websock
    "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 515, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 223, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 129, in connect
    raise WebSocketException("SSL not available.")
WebSocketException: SSL not available.
2024-08-06T16:13:58Z {'REMOTE_PORT': '54310', 'HTTP_HOST': 'MyIpaddress:45017', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', (hidden keys: 33)} failed with WebSocketException

Environment Details:

Python Version: 2.7.5
Operating System: RHEL 9
OpenSSL Version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
Installed Packages: websocket-client, gevent, etc.

What I've Tried:

Verified OpenSSL Installation:
openssl version

Output:
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017


Verified Python SSL Module:
import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

Output:
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017


Environment Variables:

SSL_CERT_FILE: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
SSL_CERT_DIR: /etc/pki/tls/certs





Questions:

Why am I getting the "SSL not available" error despite having OpenSSL installed and verified?
Are there any additional configurations or steps I need to ensure that Python can use OpenSSL for SSL/TLS connections?


How did you create the server?
